# POST attack on my website

Tags: ip-address, post, hacking

I have a site (humanisms.co.uk) which incorporates a voting system, ie. user clicks "Up" and it sends a parameter to a PHP script via AJAX, the PHP inserts vote into MYSQL db and the new "Up" vote is sent back to the page to update the vote count. This is working great but i've noticed that the number of votes for one of my questions shot up last night. I viewed my webhosts access logs and saw this line:

```
108.27.195.232 - - [03/Mar/2011:15:20:18 +0000] "POST /vote.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "http://www.humanisms.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_6; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.114 Safari/534.16"
```

This is repeated well over 100 times and sometimes more than once a second. Now i know they probably arent sitting there clicking Vote but running some sort of PHP loop?

I'm not worried about SQL injection but what can i do to prevent this same IP address from doing this or what can i do in general to avoid this scenario.

I should also say that there's no login so anyone can click using the voting system.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/make-your-site-anti-bot/3545#3545):

> You could do several things including:
>
> Use a CAPATCHA like [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.com/)
>
> Use a field that requires the user
>   to answer a question like what is 5 +
>   3. Any human can answer it but a bot won't know what to do since it is
>   auto-populating fields based on field
>   names. So that field will be either
>   incorrect or missing in which case the
>   submission will be rejected.
>
> Use a token and put it into a
>   session and also add it to the form.
>   If the token is not submitted with the
>   form or doesn't match then it is
>   automated and can be ignored.
>
> Look for repeated submissions from
>   the same IP address. If your form
>   shouldn't get too many requests but
>   suddenly is it probably is being hit
>   by a bot and you should consider
>   temporarily blocking the IP address.

Comment: sorry to extend the question, but how would i block the ip address? (using PHP?)

Comment: @benhowdle89 See [this answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9247/trigger-ip-ban-based-on-request-of-given-file/9249#9249) for an example that you should be able to edit to suit your needs.

Comment: nice! will try that!

Answer (score 2):

- Log IPs, 1 vote per IP only
- CAPTCHCA
- Use built in server side script functionality to ensure post request originated from same server

Answer (score 0):

The entire votes control can be injected with a javascript, so it's not part of the html source on your page. In order to boost 'security' and lessen the chance of abuse by automation you could

1. activate it's 'onclick' event only if you detect mouse moves within a range of that control.
2. within the server side script check for presence of a url referrer (at least the domain)
3. you can even calculate a hash of your 'caller' javascript method and send it in a disguised form to the 'voting' control to check if the 'onclick' has indeed originated from within your own script (the hash would be different within various browsers)

Etc.. But main starting point is to have the entire control injected with a javascript. This way it will also contribute to your Text/to HTML ratio on the page, as you'll have less crap within page content that a search engine sees (while it does not see the javascript)

And this way there is no need in using those dumb 'captchas' and claim your visitor's precious time by having them to prove they're not a robot...

Comment: Check out the difference between those 2 contact forms (feel free to send me a hi on both) 1. http://www.silverlightbooks.net/contact/ - with a captcha.

2. http://www.livecasinodirect.com/contact/ - without captcha. Which one would you prefer as a user ?